# How to rotate a textbox in gnuplot

Tags: textbox, gnuplot

I would like to use rotated text in a 'textbox' in gnuplot (version 5.0 patchlevel 0).
But only the text is rotated, not even the 'textbox'.

Is this a bug or intention? Does anybody know how to get rotated text in a box in a other way?

Comment: Fram the manual: _Some terminals support enclosing the label in a box. See set style textbox (p. 165). Note: Currently the
boxed enclosure is limited to unrotated text._

Comment: OK, it's not a feature (yet) - it's for the future (soon)  ;-)
Thank you

Comment: If using a latex terminal is a possibility, then you should be able to do this kind of thing putting the corresponding latex code as a label. Let me know if that would work for you and I can post an example.

Comment: @ Miguel: thank you for your help, but in the most cases i use the png terminal, sometimes postscript. I do not really need rotated text in a box, it's a nice feature. "boxed" text hides the grid and makes it all more readable, this is important for me.

Answer (score 0):

**As a late answer and an update**,
fortunately, from gnuplot 5.2.0 on you have the possibility of rotated and boxed text. I guess most (but probably not all) terminals will support boxed labels. Check `help textbox`.

**Script:**

```
### boxed labels (for gnuplot>=5.2.0)
reset session

set title "gnuplot>=5.2 rotated text with colored background"
set key opaque box
set grid x,y

set style textbox 1 opaque fc rgb 0xffffff noborder
set style textbox 2 opaque fc rgb 0xffff00 noborder
set style textbox 3 opaque fc rgb 0xffcccc noborder

set label 1 at graph 0.1,0.1 font ",16"  rotate by  60 boxed bs 1 front 'Text with white background' 
set label 2 at graph 0.3,0.3 font ",28"  rotate by  45 boxed bs 2 front 'Yellow background' 
set label 3 at graph 0.6,0.6 font ",40"  rotate by -45 boxed bs 3 front 'rotated box' 

plot sin(x)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Workaround for gnuplot 5.0.0**

Just for the records and for fun, here is a "retro-workaround" for gnuplot 5.0.0. Although, this only without borders, but you just wanted to blank the plot for better readability of the labels.

- You could use rotated labels together with rotated filled rectangles, however, calculating the proper coordinates for the rotated rectangle (actually polygon coordinates) will be some effort (see: [How to draw a rect in the diagonal using gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71909774/7295599)). The script there will also work for gnuplot5.0.0 if you replace `keyentry` with `NaN` in the plot command.
- Alternatively, instead of a rotated rectangle you could use a rotated arrow with very thick linewidths.
  However, in order to bring the arrow in front of the data you have to use the option `set arrow ... front`. Unfortunately, the layer sequence (check `help layers`) draws arrows on top of labels, so there seems to be no way to get the label in front of the arrow *and* in front of the data unless you are using `multiplot` which will make it a bit lengthy.

The drawback of the two workarounds is that you have to fiddle around finding either suitable rectangles or arrow lengths and linewidths.

**Script:**

```
### workaround for boxed labels (for gnuplot 5.0.0)
reset session

# x   y     a    l    fsize  lw   color       label
$myLabels <<EOD                  
0.1   0.1   60   36   16     35   0xffffff   'Text with white background'
0.3   0.3   45   43   28     38   0xffff00   'Yellow background'
0.6   0.6  -45   38   40     50   0xffcccc   'rotated box'
EOD

set table $Params
    set datafile separator "\n"
    ParamStr = ''
    plot $myLabels u (ParamStr=ParamStr.sprintf(' "%s" ',strcol(1)),rand(0))
    set datafile separator whitespace
unset table

posX(n)   = real(word(word(ParamStr,n),1))
posY(n)   = real(word(word(ParamStr,n),2))
angle(n)  = real(word(word(ParamStr,n),3))
length(n) = real(word(word(ParamStr,n),4))
fsize(n)  = real(word(word(ParamStr,n),5))
lw(n)     = real(word(word(ParamStr,n),6))
lc(n)     = word(word(ParamStr,n),7)
label(n)  = word(word(ParamStr,n),8)

set grid x,y

set multiplot

    set title "gnuplot 5.0 workaround for rotated text with colored background"
    set key opaque box
    plot sin(x)

    do for [i=1:words(ParamStr)] {
        set arrow i from graph posX(i),posY(i) length char length(i) angle angle(i) nohead lw lw(i) lc rgb lc(i)
        set label i   at graph posX(i),posY(i) label(i) font sprintf(",%g",fsize(i)) rotate by angle(i) front
    }
    
    set margins 0,0,0,0
    unset title
    unset key
    unset tics
    set border 0
    set origin real(GPVAL_TERM_XMIN)/(GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE/GPVAL_TERM_SCALE+1), \
               real(GPVAL_TERM_YMIN)/(GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE/GPVAL_TERM_SCALE+1)
    set size real(GPVAL_TERM_XMAX-GPVAL_TERM_XMIN)/(GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE/GPVAL_TERM_SCALE), \
             real(GPVAL_TERM_YMAX-GPVAL_TERM_YMIN)/(GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE/GPVAL_TERM_SCALE)
    plot x lt -2   # invisible curve

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot5.0.0)

[image]