# How to draw a rect in the diagonal using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I draw a rect in gnuplot but i want it to appear in the diagonal

```
set object 1 rect from 53.1035,126.27 to 133.104,146.27

I have :
     _____
    |     |
    |_____|

I want :
        _____
       /    /
      /____/
```

Comment: Do you mean a rotated recrangle or a parallelogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is not (yet) a simple option to draw a rotated rectangle.
And as @TomSolid already pointed out that in the general case you can draw a polygon "by hand".

So, if you want to rotate your rectangle you have to apply the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to your rectangle coordinates. In the example below the rotation angle is 45 degrees. If you want to rotate it by the angle of the diagonal, define the rotation angle as `a = atan(dy/dx)`

However, keep in mind the rectangle will only appear as rectangle and in the same proportions if the x- and y-axes have the same scaling factors. You can enforce this by `set size ratio -1` (check `help size`).
If x- and y-axes do not have the same scaling factors, you can also keep the (visual) proportions for your rotated rectangle, but it will require a bit more extra effort.

**Edit:** Script changed to a more general solution. Rotation center can be defined.
Furthermore, the functions for the rotated corner coordinates (`x1r(n), y1r(n), ...`) are actually not a function of `n`, but this way the functions will take the current values of `x0,y0,x1,y1` at the time of calling.

**Script:**

```
### draw a rotated rectangle
reset session

x0 = 53.1035
y0 = 126.27
x1 = 133.104
y1 = 146.27

set obj 1 rect from x0,y0 to x1,y1 
set obj 1 fs empty border rgb "red"

set size ratio -1

set angle degrees
a  = 45     # rotation angle
xc = x0     # rotation around bottom...
yc = y0     # ...left corner x0,y0

# functions for rotation of rectangle corner coordinates
x1r(n) = xc+(x0-xc)*cos(a)-(y0-yc)*sin(a)
y1r(n) = yc+(x0-xc)*sin(a)+(y0-yc)*cos(a)
x2r(n) = xc+(x1-xc)*cos(a)-(y0-yc)*sin(a)
y2r(n) = yc+(x1-xc)*sin(a)+(y0-yc)*cos(a)
x3r(n) = xc+(x1-xc)*cos(a)-(y1-yc)*sin(a)
y3r(n) = yc+(x1-xc)*sin(a)+(y1-yc)*cos(a)
x4r(n) = xc+(x0-xc)*cos(a)-(y1-yc)*sin(a)
y4r(n) = yc+(x0-xc)*sin(a)+(y1-yc)*cos(a)

set obj 2 polygon from x1r(0),y1r(0) to x2r(0),y2r(0) to x3r(0),y3r(0) to x4r(0),y4r(0) to x1r(0),y1r(0)
set obj 2 fs empty border rgb "blue"

a = atan(real(y1-y0)/(x1-x0))       # real() to avoid potential integer division
xc = (x0+x1)/2.                     # rotation around...
yc = (y0+y1)/2.                     # ...rectangle center

set obj 3 polygon from x1r(0),y1r(0) to x2r(0),y2r(0) to x3r(0),y3r(0) to x4r(0),y4r(0) to x1r(0),y1r(0)
set obj 3 fs empty border rgb "green"

set xrange [0:150]
set yrange [100:200]
set key top left

plot NaN notitle, \
     keyentry w l lc "red" ti "original rectangle", \
     keyentry w l lc "blue" ti "rotated by 45° around x0,y0", \
     keyentry w l lc "green" ti "rotated by diagonal around center"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
set object polygon from <position> to <position> to <position>
```